# Collision detection management in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection

After reading this:
[Managing Collision Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311034/managing-collision-detection-in-games)

I thought about how to manage it in libgdx as it supports other collision detection (using Intersector) and other classes you can use in game.
I have the logic of my Objects with their properties (Zombie for example with moving Speed and health) and the appearance with the Textures, Position on Screen etc.( Zombie2d for example which is a subclass of Actor). The Zombie2d has also a reference to Zombie to have all the attributes of a Zombie. The Question: Should every Actor have a Reference to the Level where all other Objects are stored and detect the collision on his own or should I have a Manager with the Level as reference?
Should i do the collision detection inside the Actor.act(delta) method or between Actor.act() and Actor.draw()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should every Actor have a Reference to the Level where all other Objects are stored and detect the collision on his own or should i have a Manager with the Level as reference?

It depends on your game, for example, games like this: [SuperJumper](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper).

With very simple collisions (Platforms/Squirrels/Coins/etc only collide with Bob, but they don't collide with each other) are easily handled within the [World](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper/blob/master/core/src/com/badlogicgames/superjumper/World.java) class. Like this:

```
//for example, Bob colliding with squirrels
private void checkSquirrelCollisions(){
    int len = squirrels.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        Squirrel squirrel = squirrels.get(i);
        if (squirrel.bounds.overlaps(bob.bounds)){
            bob.hitSquirrel();
            listener.hit();
        }
    }
}
```

But a more complex Game which had Enemies/Bullets/etc that collide with Each Other/Walls/Player/etc would find a cleaner code if each one handled its own collisions.

> Should I do the collision detection inside the Actor.act(delta) method or between Actor.act() and Actor.draw()?

Well, as the collisions take an important role in the Entity behaviour (for example bouncing, stopping movement, etc). It would be better to have it inside the `Actor.act(delta)` method.

Comment: In my game i have Enemies/Bullets etc so the second case is what i Need. Question: When the Player collides with the enemie the Player and the enemie detect this collision so should they both only call their own reaction or also the reaction of the other and "stop" this collision?

Comment: Make them to call the reaction of the other aswell, because by the time the other check its collisions,the first one probably already moved (bouncing for example).

Comment: +1 for your answer. Until now i had a CollisionManager who managed the collision detection but i think this is a better solution