# How can I detect collision between two actor in libGDX ?

Tags: libgdx, collision-detection

I have two actor, one is "cake" and another one is "some flying object". I want to detect contact or collision when the "some flying object" contact with the "cake". How can i exactly detect it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collision detection management in Libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109340/collision-detection-management-in-libgdx)

Answer (score 0):

Luckily there is a nice API called Bullet, and LibGDX gives us a wrapper in order to use it (Bullet is coded in C++). Bullet aims to manage all the physic in games. To see how it works, I recommend this tutorial from xoppa : https://xoppa.github.io/blog/using-the-libgdx-3d-physics-bullet-wrapper-part1/